# Filemaker portal: multiple keys per record

Tags: filemaker

(edit)
Having a table with a self-relation: items / items-related.
Record B needs to have 2 keys: blue & red (of course, in the real table the colours will be id’s)
I don’t want all the red records be shown in the portal on record X.
How would I do that?

[image]

Comment: Your question is too abstract to provide an answer. It seems you want to use **two** key fields - one defining which records to show in the portal when this record is the current one, and one to determine when to show this record in the portal. A better explanation of what exactly are you trying to accomplish here (and why) might lead to a better answer.

Comment: Thank you f or the brisk reply. I added a brief explanation. How would I use two key fields?

Comment: "*I added a brief explanation.*" I meant explain the **real** problem you're trying to solve here, not the **technique** you are trying to implement in order to solve it.  See: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the structure shown in your picture, your `items` table should look like this:

**Either:**

```
ItemID  ItemName    ChildItemsIDs
A       Alpha
B       Bravo
C       Charlie
D       Delta
X       Xray        A¶B
Y       Yankee      B¶C¶D
```

*(the `¶` symbol stands for carriage return)*

and the relationship should be defined as:

```
items::ChildItemsIDs = items_related::ItemID
```

with a portal to `items_related:` placed on a layout of `items`.

**Or:**

```
ItemID  ItemName    ParentItemsIDs
A       Alpha       X
B       Bravo       X¶Y
C       Charlie     Y
D       Delta       Y
X       Xray        
Y       Yankee
```

with the relationship defined as:

```
items::ItemID = items_related::ParentItemsIDs
```

The choice between these two options depends on whether you want to select the children for a parent or the parents for a child.

---

**Note**:
You are describing a *many-to-many* relationship between `items` and itself. The "proper" solution for this is to use a *join table*, where each linked pair of items would be an individual record.

Filemaker allows you to implement a many-to-many relationship without requiring a join table, by using a [multi-valued key](http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/glossary.html#1027937) as shown above. However, there are downsides to this convenience: you cannot record any attributes that are specific to a join, and producing a report is more difficult (portals do not print well across page breaks).

Comment: Thank you. Although it cost some time to really 'crack the code', for it was like finding my way backwards from the labyrinth I made of my initial tables&relation, your answer triggered me to think and work in the right direction. I choose to do it right this time by indeed including a join table. This involved some extra work to link records correctly again, but I gladly did.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

First, if you intend to use sequential integers for your primary keys (NOT recommended in most cases), your field should be a number field, rather than a text field. Depending on how you've set up your self join, changing this might resolve your problem immediately.

However. Although it's valid to use multikeys for FileMaker relationships, it's often better to use a conventiona many-to many-join. To do this, you'd set up a separate join table with "parent" record (record you're viewing) as the "left" secondary key, and the "child" record (a record you want to appear in the portal) as the "right" secondary key, then you'd join your main table occurrence to a new secondary TO in your relationship graph connected by this new join table. By doing this, you get a rock solid mechanism to do what you want, as well as the ability to later fields specific to each instance of a "child" for a specific "parent" in this join table. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

One other note: Noticing your new added text about a portal filter:

To do this, you'd set up a Cartesian join (using the "X" operator in the relationship graph, creating a relationship that "sees" all other records (and in the case of a self-join, also the current record itself. You then apply a portal filter which will be evaluated for each record in the relationship: You create an expression that, when evaluated for a given related record evaluates the true, the record displays; otherwise, the record is hidden.

This is a tempting approach, and at first, you'd likely love it. However, it would likely fail over time. The reason is that this technique becomes increasingly slow as you add more records or as you pass data across LAN and WAN environments - often too slow to be usable. In addition, a filtered portal still "sees" all its non-filtered records, so this approach would block you from being able to do other things to these related records, such as get the 1st, 2nd one, get a total count of them, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Although it cost some time to really 'crack the code', for it was like finding my way backwards from the labyrinth I made of my initial tables&relation, your answer triggered me to think and work in the right direction. I choose to do it right this time by indeed including a join table. This involved some extra work to link records correctly again, but I gladly did.

Comment: great! glad to hear it helped. and honestly, you'll be much happier having taken the time up front :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is very confusing. I'll try to help based on what I understood of your problem

You have a table "items" that is self-related; the other Table Occurrence is named "items_related"

You have a relationship that is not one to many. If you had a one-to-many, I'd advise you to have a field called foreingKey_Father and to make the relationship this way: "items::foreignKey_Father = items_related::primaryKey"

If your relationship is more complicated, the right way to solve this is with a join table. It could be named "JT_itemToItemRelated" with two fields "foreignKey_item" and "foreignKey_itemRelated". This way, the portal would filter the related items based on the record of the join table.

If you want the relationship to be based on several related IDs in a text field, you could (but shouldn't) do that. All you must do is make the items::variousPrimaryKeys = items_related::primaryKey. That's not a better practice.

If you could give more info on what you are trying to accomplish it would be faster.